# How can I bin data in bigvis package R for a non-numeric data set?

Tags: r, bigdata

I am trying to use `bin()` on my big data set. I am using the Lahman data set as an example: http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/

I am using the comma-delimited version and looking at the 'Batting' csv file. My data set will be much, much bigger, but if my program cannot handle this, it can't handle my bigger data set.

This is what I am trying to do currently:

```
> require(devtools)
> require(bigvis)
> bigData <- read.csv("GCdataViz/lahman2012-csv/Batting.csv")
> bigDataNum <- bigData[,sapply(bigData,is.numeric)]
> bin(bigDataNum)
Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

I first got an error when I tried to use `bin()` because my data set wasn't all numeric. So I used `sapply()` with the `is.numeric` parameter, but still got the error that my data set wasn't numeric.

The bigvis library doesn't have much documentation. Should I `smooth()` after the condense method or go ahead and `autoplot()`. Is there anyway I can specify plots like bar graphs, line graphs, box, etc?

EDIT: my error:

Comment: I assume you have tried `bin(bigDataNum)`, despite not showing it in your example? Does `str(bigDataNum)` look as you expect?

Comment: I still get the same error after using bigDataNum(I accidentally named it bigData in my example). Updated the post

Comment: Yes, str(bigDataNum) looks like I would expect, it has all the non-numeric columns taken out. There are a lot of NA values, however, in the columns, but I don't think this would affect the bin.

Comment: Well, if you don't manage with `bin`, why not try `ggplot` or something in base R. `bigvis` is developed for "large datasets (10-100 million obs).". Your dataset has less than 100K rows - i.e. no problem with more 'standard' methods. You haven't presented your objectives with the plot. However, if you think of splitting your plots on categorical variables such as player, year, team etc, then ggplot is veeery convenient. You can also handel overplotting easily in ggplot.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into ggplot instead and just give up on bigVis

Comment: If you are new to ggplot I can recommend these:
http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2, http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/, http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/. Good luck!

Comment: Stumbled över this: http://lahman.r-forge.r-project.org/. Something for you?

Comment: You may find this tutorial helpful, where they use `ggplot` on the `diamonds` data with >50k rows: http://teachpress.environmentalinformatics-marburg.de/2013/07/creating-publication-quality-graphs-in-r-7/

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for linking me these, they might be exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad to help! As you will find, 'ordinary' ggplot have many ways to handle overplotting of large data, see e.g. alpha-argument, jittering, stat_bin2d, stat_binhex, stat_density2d. Good luck!